# Reclass in ModelBuilder - Stopping at Random Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, reclassify, viewshed

I've created 5,000 viewshed rasters for ~5,000 sites in my study area. Using ModelBuilder, I am trying to reclass these rasters so that all "0" values are now "NoData".

When I iterate across all rasters in my folder, it seems to work well until I get to the 4,001th raster. Then the operation stops and I receive an error message. This has happened three times.

It doesn't seem to be a matter associated with naming, as the operation works for the first 4,000 rasters. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? I don't have the error message recorded, unfortunately, but I'm wondering if anyone has come up on similar issues.

Comment: I've come across similar situations with model builder and it's probably some sort of memory leak. I would restart your model at 4001 and let it continue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I must admit ignorance here. How do you restrict the model to only run on those observations from, say, 4000 to 5000 if I'd be restricting based on a file name, rather than a feature value? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A model with a [For](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/for.htm) Iterator can be used to help construct raster dataset names that can then feed into your workflow.

A simple example is shown below. See how the output of the iterator called *value* is used as in an inline substitution (the %value%) in the calculate value tool to create a raster dataset path which can feed into the raster to point tool. You would also use the inline substitution in that tool to create valid and unique file names.

[image: Example model]